# Ingesting logs from Fluentbit into Splunk -- Connection reset by peer

Tags: kubernetes, splunk, fluentd, fluent

We are trying to ingest logs through Fluentbit into Splunk. This is our test instance and hence both are running as Kubernetes PODs in the same cluster and namespace. Unfortunately, we keep getting "Recv failure: Connection reset by peer" error. The following is what i tried subsequently to isolate the issue

1. Use a CURL command from the POD which ingests logs into Splunk POD

   ```
   curl -vvv
   http://splunk-deployment-server-service.devnamespace.svc:8089/services/collector
   -H 'Authorization: Welcome1' -d '{"sourcetype": "manual-testing", "event":"Hello Splunk, 
   World!", "index":"cf"}'
   ```

The above gives us the following message

```
Trying 172.20.5.31...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to splunk-deployment-server-service.devnamespace.svc (172.20.5.31) port 8089 (#0)
> POST /services/collector HTTP/1.1
> Host: splunk-deployment-server-service.devnamespace.svc:8089
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Welcome1
> Content-Length: 78
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 78 out of 78 bytes
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

2. Tried the same from splunk POD itself using the following command

   ```
   curl -vvv http://localhost:8089/services/collector -H 'Authorization: Welcome1' -d '{"sourcetype": "manual-testing", "event":"Hello Splunk, World!", "index":"cf"}'
   ```

The above also gets similar error,

```
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
 TCP_NODELAY set
 Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8089 (#0)
> POST /services/collector HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8089
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Welcome1
> Content-Length: 78
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
 upload completely sent off: 78 out of 78 bytes
 Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
 Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

Versions:
Splunk 9.1.0.1
Fluent Bit v2.0.4

Thanks
Bala

Comment: Have you specified HEC token in your request?

Comment: @Vad1m thanks for your response. Yes, i did specify the HEC token. Another update, i am able to successfully send the request on port 8088 and not on port 8089.

Comment: The HEC port is 8088. Why do you use MGMT port 8089 instead?